# How to write to multiple files on different disks simultaneously in one thread with DMA?

Tags: linux, dma, solid-state-drive, aio

I use aio to write multiple files on different disk in one thread. When I use buffered writing, IO processing is concurrent. But cpu loads is very high. When I open files with DIRECT flag, IO processing isn't concurrent.

How to write to multiple files on different disks simultaneously in one thread with DMA?

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/aio_abi.h>

using namespace std;

long double timeDiff(timespec start, timespec end) {
const long double s = start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec * 1.0e-9;
const long double e = end.tv_sec   + end.tv_nsec   * 1.0e-9;
return e - s;
}

// nr: maximum number of requests that can simultaneously reside in the context.
inline int io_setup(unsigned nr, aio_context_t *ctxp) {
return syscall(__NR_io_setup, nr, ctxp);
}

inline int io_destroy(aio_context_t ctx) {
return syscall(__NR_io_destroy, ctx);
}

// Every I/O request that is submitted to 
inline int io_submit(aio_context_t ctx, long nr, struct iocb **iocbpp) {
return syscall(__NR_io_submit, ctx, nr, iocbpp);
}

// For every completed I/O request kernel creates an io_event structure.
// minimal number of events one wants to get.
// maximum number of events one wants to get.
inline int io_getevents(aio_context_t ctx, long min_nr, long max_nr,
    struct io_event *events, struct timespec *timeout) {
return syscall(__NR_io_getevents, ctx, min_nr, max_nr, events, timeout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

// prepare data
const unsigned int kAlignment = 4096;
const long data_size = 1600 * 1024 * 12 / 8; 
//const long data_size = 2448 * 1344 * 12 / 8; 
void * data = memalign(kAlignment, data_size);
memset(data, 0, data_size);
//for (int i = 0; i < data_size; ++i)
//   data[i] = 'A';

// prepare fd
//const int file_num = 3;
const int file_num = 2;
int fd_arr[file_num];
for (int i = 0; i < file_num; ++i) {
    ostringstream filename;
    if (i == 0) {
        //filename << "/data/test";
        filename << "/test";
    } else {
        filename << "/data" << i << "/test";
    }
    //filename << "/data/test" << i;
    int fd = open(filename.str().c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK | O_CREAT | O_DIRECT | O_APPEND, 0644);
    //int fd = open(filename.str().c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK | O_CREAT | O_DIRECT, 0644);
    //int fd = open(filename.str().c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }
    fd_arr[i] = fd;
}

aio_context_t ctx;
struct io_event events[file_num];
int ret;
ctx = 0;

ret = io_setup(1000, &ctx);
if (ret < 0) {
    perror("io_setup");
    return -1;
}

struct iocb cbs[file_num];
for (int i = 0; i < file_num; ++i) {
    memset(&cbs[i], 0, sizeof(cbs[i]));
}
struct iocb * cbs_pointer[file_num];
for (int i = 0; i < file_num; ++i) {
    /* setup I/O control block */
    cbs_pointer[i] = &cbs[i];
    cbs[i].aio_fildes = fd_arr[i];
    cbs[i].aio_lio_opcode = IOCB_CMD_PWRITE; // IOCV_CMD
    cbs[i].aio_nbytes = data_size;
}

timespec tStart, tCurr;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tStart);

const int frame_num = 10000;
for (int k = 0; k < frame_num; ++k) {

    for (int i = 0; i < file_num; ++i) {
        /* setup I/O control block */
        cbs[i].aio_buf = (uint64_t)data;
        //cbs[i].aio_offset = k * data_size;
    }

    ret = io_submit(ctx, file_num, cbs_pointer);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("io_submit");
        return -1;
    }

    /* get reply */
    ret = io_getevents(ctx, file_num, file_num, events, NULL);
    //printf("events: %d, k: %d\n", ret, k);
}

clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tCurr);
cout << "frame: " << frame_num << " time: " << timeDiff(tStart, tCurr) << endl;

ret = io_destroy(ctx);
if (ret < 0) {
    perror("io_destroy");
    return -1;
}

// close fd
for (int i = 0; i < file_num; ++i) {
    fsync(fd_arr[i]);
    close(fd_arr[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux can make writes actually async if and only if the physical extents being written are allocated on the disc already. Otherwise it has to take a mutex and do the allocation first, thus everything becomes synchronous.

Note that truncating the file to a new length usually doesn't actually allocate the underlying extents. You need to prewrite the contents first. Thereafter, *rewriting* the same extents will now be done async and thus become concurrent.

As you might be gathering, async file i/o on Linux is not great, though it keeps on getting better over time. Windows or FreeBSD have far superior implementations. Even OS X is not terrible. Use any of those instead.

Comment: Thank you! What's the difference between whether opening file with O_DIRECT flag? Without it the total bandwidth is bigger than one disk write bandwidth, but CPU loads are high. With it the total bandwidth is same as one disk bandwidth.

Comment: Without `O_DIRECT` all i/o goes to the kernel page cache first i.e. `memcpy()`, and then at some later stage it'll get DMAed to disc. With `O_DIRECT` on, if the block you are writing is a 4Kb multiple aligned to a 4Kb boundary and you **do no access to that memory during the i/o**, chances are good it'll be DMAed directly without an intervening `memcpy()`. Of course, if you're allocating of new extents, as I mentioned that's a global mutex so you'll serialise and lose concurrency.